# VBA code for deleting columns that contain a specific string with the function Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to get rid of the columns that contain a specific string in a cell. The code is as follows:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim state As String
Dim num As Variant
num = InputBox("Enter the state", "What stx is it?", "Enter x here")
'the & will combine them together
state = "st" & num
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'Uses all the columns in use due to the previous line
 For j = 2 To .Columns.Count
    If .Cells(2, j).Formula = state Then
    'Do nothing
    Else
    Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
 Next j
End With
End Sub
```

I start at `j=2` because I do not want to erase the first column. 
[Here is a snippet of my data I am trying to modify.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOjum.png)
However, this doesn't erase all the columns that contain the specific cell. What puzzles me is that if I replace

```
 Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

with

```
Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

it correctly highlights all the cells that I want to delete.

Comment: when deleting rows or columns always loop backwards, `For j =  .Columns.Count To 2 Step -1`

Comment: Thank your for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting rows with a loop you should always run backwards, as when you delete a row, j increases by 1 and means you skip a row.

Replace

```
For j = 2 To .Columns.Count
```

For

```
For j = .Columns.Count To 2 Step -1
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `Step -1` will set me back one cell, and in this case, from the end?

Comment: Yes this will start at the very last row, and work backwards through your data. This ensures no rows are skipped. When running forwards lets say j = 5 and it deletes that row, this means row 6 is now row 5, but j now equals 6, so the original row 6 has been missed out all together.

Comment: Oh that is why; that make sense. Thank you for your time and wisdom.